# C++: How to display the last five names/lines when reading from a file?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to get this function to read the last five lines of a file. This is all I have so far. A similarly structured function that finds the first five lines and displays them worked fine and so does the part of this function that counts up the total number of lines.

Everything else seems to work fine except this part and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried multiple different solutions (aka just moving the code around and deleting lines to see if it would help) but nothing worked. It can, however, display 46-50 with the colons but not the last five lines. If I were to display the names before the for loop part and within the while loop counting part, it would successfully display all of the names.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks. (sorry if I'm not formatting this correctly)

```
void displayLastFive(ifstream & fin)
{
    char name[81];
    int totalNumberOfLines = 0;

    fin.getline(name, 81);

    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0L, ios::beg);

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.getline(name, 81);
        totalNumberOfLines++;
    }

    for (int i = totalNumberOfLines - 5; i < totalNumberOfLines; i++)
    {
        fin.getline(name, 81);
        cout << i + 1 << ": " << name << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210353/discussion-on-question-by-mrambiguous-c-how-to-display-the-last-five-names-li).

Answer (score 0):

answer was much simpler than I thought

```
 void displayLastFive(ifstream & fin)
{
    char name[81];
    int totalNumberOfLines;

    totalNumberOfLines = count(fin);

    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0L, ios::beg);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfLines; i++)
    {
        fin.getline(name, 81);
        if (i >= totalNumberOfLines - 5)
        {
            cout << i + 1 << ": " << name << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```